# right way to specify the src for an image in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following code:

```
<img src="images/img2.jpg" alt="" title="" />
```

Is this correct for `Layout.cshtml` and partial views?

Should I instead specify the source using something like `@URl`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will probably gonna break. The below one is the right way of doing it :

```
<img src="@Url.Content("~/images/img2.jpg")" alt="" title="" />
```

Comment: Also check out t4mvc for strongly typed content links.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `ImageExtensions` Helper function from the Mvc3Futures\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.dll.

You can find it in [NuGet repository](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/Mvc3Futures).

```
public static class ImageExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageRelativeUrl);

    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageRelativeUrl, string alt);

    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageRelativeUrl, string alt, object htmlAttributes);

    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageRelativeUrl, object htmlAttributes);

    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageRelativeUrl, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);

    public static MvcHtmlString Image(this HtmlHelper helper, string imageRelativeUrl, string alt, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);

    public static TagBuilder Image(string imageUrl, string alt, IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes);
}
```